# Add submit button to jquery search form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a submit and a clear button to a quicksearch form in flexigrid. At the moment, when a user searches, they have press the enter key (13). So in conjunction with that, I would also like buttons that search and clear. I know I did this before, but cannot find the code after a restore. Many thanks

```
//add search button
if (p.searchitems) {
    $('.pDiv2', g.pDiv).prepend("<div class='pGroup'> <div class='pSearch pButton'><span></span></div> </div>  <div class='btnseparator'></div>");
    $('.pSearch', g.pDiv).click(function () {
        $(g.sDiv).slideToggle('fast', function () {
            $('.sDiv:visible input:first', g.gDiv).trigger('focus');
        });
    });
    //add search box
    g.sDiv.className = 'sDiv';
    var sitems = p.searchitems;
    var sopt = '', sel = '';
    for (var s = 0; s < sitems.length; s++) {
        if (p.qtype == '' && sitems[s].isdefault == true) {
            p.qtype = sitems[s].name;
            sel = 'selected="selected"';
        } else {
            sel = '';
        }
        sopt += "<option value='" + sitems[s].name + "' " + sel + " >" + sitems[s].display + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>";
    }
    if (p.qtype == '') {
        p.qtype = sitems[0].name;
    }
    $(g.sDiv).append("<div class='sDiv2'>" + p.findtext + 
            " <input type='text' value='" + p.query +"' size='30' name='q' class='qsbox' /> "+
            " <select name='qtype'>" + sopt + "</select></div>");
    //Split into separate selectors because of bug in jQuery 1.3.2
    $('input[name=q]', g.sDiv).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            g.doSearch();
        }
    });
    $('select[name=qtype]', g.sDiv).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            g.doSearch();
        }
    });
    $('input[value=Clear]', g.sDiv).click(function () {
        $('input[name=q]', g.sDiv).val('');
        p.query = '';
        g.doSearch();
    });
    $(g.bDiv).after(g.sDiv);
}
```

Comment: I don't know flexigrid but why can't you use append() and remove() jquery function ?

Comment: @kero not sure I follow you? the buttons need to appear around this area: $(g.sDiv).append("<div class='sDiv2'>" + p.findtext + of the code but not sure how to code it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok you can try something simple like that :

```
$('.sDiv2').append("<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit' /><input type='reset' value='reset' name='reset' />");
```

After you set listeners like you did for the others input

Comment: what is confusing me, is even if i put a button like i have here, it dosen't even show never mind work: $(g.sDiv).append("<div class='sDiv2'>" + p.findtext + 
      " <input type='text' value='" + p.query +"' size='30' name='q' class='qsbox' /> "+
      " <select name='qtype'>" + sopt + "</select>" + "<input type='button' value='Search' />" + "</div>");
    //Split into separate selectors because of bug in jQuery 1.3.2
    $('input[name=q]', g.sDiv).keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      g.doSearch();
     }

Comment: got it sorted. Just needed to add $('input[value=Search]', g.sDiv).click(function () {p.query = '';
   g.doSearch();
   }); Many thanks for the good steer